# Optimization - Best practice to return an empty string in C

Tags: c, optimization, memory, string-literals

I have two functions, and both can return an empty string, so what is the best practice to save memory and avoid duplicated .txt empty string?

**Example**

```
const char* function_one() {
    return "";
}
const char* function_two() {
    return "";
}
int main() {
    printf("One: %s\n", function_one());
    printf("Two: %s\n", function_two());
}
```

**Is this optimization correct ?**

```
const char* empty = "";
const char* function_one() {
    return empty;
}
const char* function_two() {
    return empty;
}
int main() {
    printf("One: %s\n", function_one());
    printf("Two: %s\n", function_two());
}
```

Comment: That's probably exactly what your compiler would do for you if you just `return "";` in both functions. Turn optimizations to max and check the address to see if that's the case. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Max8W5M6n). gcc, clang and msvc all optimize your first version to return the same string.

Comment: You are right, https://onecompiler.com/c/3yp97vnbw

Comment: So, the answer is we don't need to do any optimization as the compiler will do it for us.

Comment: Compilers are even allowed to let them overlap. If you return `"Hello world"` from one function and `"world"` from another, you may find that `"world"` is a pointer into the `"Hello world"` string.

Comment: Awesome, I got what I need, would you please write a little answer to help others?

Comment: You could define it as an array instead: `const char empty[] = "";`. In theory that needs less space because it is only storing a `char` instead of a `char *` and a `char`.

Comment: This kind of hand-optimization may be useful if you define the string in one translation unit and want to reuse it in many others. That'll be harder for the optimizer to realize (I think).

Comment: @AlbertShown Would have written an answer, but Vlad beat me to it (again) :-D

Comment: Declaring it as an array also avoids the possibility of `empty` being reassigned to point to something else.  More clearly and safely to my eye than declaring it as `const char * const empty;` would do, though the latter is indeed another alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually compilers by default store identical string literals as one string literal in the literal pool. In any case they provide an option that can control that.

So this code

```
const char* function_one() {
    return "";
}
const char* function_two() {
    return "";
}
```

in fact is equivalent to this code

```
const char* empty = "";
const char* function_one() {
    return empty;
}
const char* function_two() {
    return empty;
}
```

except in the last code there is created a redundant global variable.

You can check the default strategy of your compiler for example the following wat

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* function_one() {
    return "";
}
const char* function_two() {
    return "";
}

int main(void) {
    printf( "%s\n", function_one() == function_two() ? "equal" : "not equal" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best practice to save memory and avoid duplicated .txt empty string?

The best practice is to not fixate on the *one char* it takes represent an empty string, nor even the handful of additional bytes that might accompany it for alignment purposes.  It is much more valuable to make your code clear, and using string literals serves that objective in this case.

Even so, this probably is not an either / or situation.  It is likely that your compiler will merge identical string literals, so that it's not an issue in the first place.

More generally, don't go out of your way to attempt hand optimization.  Write clean code using algorithms and data structures appropriate for your objectives, implemented with reasonable efficiency.  Revisit that only when you determine that there is an actual problem to be solved by micro-optimizations such as you are considering.

Comment: Agreed: [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/94903).